# unresolved external linking to static Qwt build

Tags: c++, qt, static-libraries, qwt

I'm trying to link to a static build of Qwt. to create the static build, I modified `qwtconfig.pri` to contain

```
#QWT_CONFIG += QwtDll
```

and I removed all the `#define QWT_DLL` references in the code.

However, when I link to the library, I get a bunch of undefined references complaining about QSvgRenderer:

```
15>qwt.lib(qwt_symbol.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl QSvgRenderer::QSvgRenderer(class QObject *)" (__imp_??0QSvgRenderer@@QEAA@PEAVQObject@@@Z) referenced in function "public: void __cdecl QwtSymbol::setSvgDocument(class QByteArray const &)" (?setSvgDocument@QwtSymbol@@QEAAXAEBVQByteArray@@@Z)
15>qwt.lib(qwt_symbol.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual __cdecl QSvgRenderer::~QSvgRenderer(void)" (__imp_??1QSvgRenderer@@UEAA@XZ) referenced in function "public: virtual void * __cdecl QSvgRenderer::`scalar deleting destructor'(unsigned int)" (??_GQSvgRenderer@@UEAAPEAXI@Z)
15>qwt.lib(qwt_symbol.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: bool __cdecl QSvgRenderer::isValid(void)const " (__imp_?isValid@QSvgRenderer@@QEBA_NXZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl qwtDrawSvgSymbols(class QPainter *,class QPointF const *,int,class QSvgRenderer *,class QwtSymbol const &)" (?qwtDrawSvgSymbols@@YAXPEAVQPainter@@PEBVQPointF@@HPEAVQSvgRenderer@@AEBVQwtSymbol@@@Z)
15>qwt.lib(qwt_symbol.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: class QRectF __cdecl QSvgRenderer::viewBoxF(void)const " (__imp_?viewBoxF@QSvgRenderer@@QEBA?AVQRectF@@XZ) referenced in function "public: virtual class QRect __cdecl QwtSymbol::boundingRect(void)const " (?boundingRect@QwtSymbol@@UEBA?AVQRect@@XZ)
15>qwt.lib(qwt_symbol.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: bool __cdecl QSvgRenderer::load(class QByteArray const &)" (__imp_?load@QSvgRenderer@@QEAA_NAEBVQByteArray@@@Z) referenced in function "public: void __cdecl QwtSymbol::setSvgDocument(class QByteArray const &)" (?setSvgDocument@QwtSymbol@@QEAAXAEBVQByteArray@@@Z)
15>qwt.lib(qwt_symbol.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __cdecl QSvgRenderer::render(class QPainter *,class QRectF const &)" (__imp_?render@QSvgRenderer@@QEAAXPEAVQPainter@@AEBVQRectF@@@Z) referenced in function "public: void __cdecl QwtSymbol::drawSymbol(class QPainter *,class QRectF const &)const " (?drawSymbol@QwtSymbol@@QEBAXPEAVQPainter@@AEBVQRectF@@@Z)
15>qwt.lib(qwt_symbol.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual struct QMetaObject const * __cdecl QSvgRenderer::metaObject(void)const " (?metaObject@QSvgRenderer@@UEBAPEBUQMetaObject@@XZ)
15>qwt.lib(qwt_symbol.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual int __cdecl QSvgRenderer::qt_metacall(enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (?qt_metacall@QSvgRenderer@@UEAAHW4Call@QMetaObject@@HPEAPEAX@Z)
15>qwt.lib(qwt_symbol.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void * __cdecl QSvgRenderer::qt_metacast(char const *)" (?qt_metacast@QSvgRenderer@@UEAAPEAXPEBD@Z)
15>C:\workspace\fixQwt\executables\linkerGUI\bin\Release\linkerGUI.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 9 unresolved externals
```

Is there something else in the project configuration I need to do so it can link properly to `QSvgRenderer`?

Comment: What compiler / platform are you using?

Comment: @demonplus msvc 2013 on windows 7.

Comment: did you make static build of qt?

Comment: @demonplus no, is it required for a static build of qwt?

Comment: yes, I think it may be required for make static build of qwt to link properly to your app. Need to search more info about this

Comment: @NicolasHolthaus I know it has been years but were you ever able to get this resolved? I have also having trouble linking a static qwt lib to a non static qt build

Comment: @rudyb I don't think so, pretty sure I reverted to a dynamic build

Answer (score 1):

Guess your version of Qt is without SVG support - or you forget to add it to your project dependency. If you are not interested in SVG stuff at all you could also disable it in qwtconfig.pri as well:

See: "QWT_CONFIG     += QwtSvg"

Comment: thanks Uwe. I actually do use the svg feature of the `QwtPlotRenderer`. It all works if I do the shared library build, it's just when I comment out `#QWT_CONFIG += QwtDll` that I have problems